# Is it possible to have Virtuemart work with a machine like Just Eat?

Tags: joomla-2.5, virtuemart, emails

Our clients are fast food takeaways and we use Joomla 2.5 and VM3 for the websites. We print out the admin order confirmation e-mail for them on Star TSP printers (not very wide paper).

Some have requested that we implement a machine similar to Just Eat. This is a machine that prints out the order, and has a few buttons to allow the user to accept or decline the order. Does something like this exist? If so would it be compatible with J2.5 and VM3? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't think VirtueMart would be the best option at all for a system like Just Eat. Nor Joomla for that matter.

Comment: We have it working well with computers and star printers. Tbh I doubted it would be possible with VM to have a machine like this. What system would you recommend so I could try it out?

Comment: I don't know as I've never look into building a system like this, nor do I know which pre-developed system are good or bad. You would have to test some and see if that suit your needs

Comment: Alright but thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After months of thorough research, I conclude that this is not possible. This is because Virtuemart works with e-mails for order confirmation, whereas Just Eat uses something else.